# Data Junction table - how many relations should it contain?

Tags: database, sql

I have a junction table, say for People and Locations

### PersonLocations

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
    2          5
```

Now, Locations can belong to each other i.e. one location can sit inside another, which can sit inside another etc., so I have this defined by the `Location` table referencing itself:

### Locations

```
LocationId | ArbitraryName | ParentLocationId
--------------------------------------------
    1          a country           null
    2          region a              1
    3          village 1             2
    4          village 2             2
    5          region b              1
```

So you can see `village 1` and `village 2` belong to `region a`, which in turn belongs to `a country`

Now, I want it to be known that if person `1` visited Location `3` (`village 1`) as shown in the first table, they also visited Location `2` and `1` - which can be inferred by the `Location` table self-referencing.

But what I've done is written rules (triggers) so that if an entry occurs on the `PersonLocations` table it automatically inserts the `ParentLocationId` (which recursively works until ParentLocationId is null)

so inserting

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
```

actually results in

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
    1          2
    1          1
```

And vice versa if I remove.

What I really want to know is - **is this safe?** It makes my queries and views much easier but am I missing something that is later going to bite me in the backside? I feel like as long as those triggers in place it would be fine, although its taking up more space - the payoff justifies it?

Comment: What happens when the data is: `(LocationID, ParentLocationID); (1, 2); (2, 1);` then insert `(PersonID, LocationID); (1,1)`?

Comment: That'd be another trigger to prevent circular referencing on the `Location` table - I think I've decided to move away from the input of unnecessary data on the Person-Location table. I don't think it's safe. I feel like I'm violating a rule I've never read but probably definitely exists!

Comment: What happens if Person 1 has previously visited "village 1" (location 3) and now visits "village 2" (location 4), which shares some parents. What should happen if you re-organize your locations and "region a" becomes part of "b country", or you split "region a" in 2 or you add another level of locations (e.g. "department x")?

Comment: The visiting shared parents wouldn't matter too much because I'd had an insert if not existing rule so the shared parents wouldn't be added twice but actually yes, reorganising the location structure that would be a massive issue - I knew there'd be some simple cases that could really screw me over I just couldn't think ahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not safe.

The biggest risk is the absence of guarantee of an inclusion graph without cycle. If you have a cycle in your graph, your trigger will just fill the database until some limits is reach, i.e. storage is exhausted, nested/recursive trigger limit is reached, or stack overflow.

Example:

```
1          a corrupt country     5           // OUCH!!!!
2          region a              1
3          village 1             2
4          village 2             2
5          region b              1
```

You can easily prevent this risk by making sure that the trigger only inserts "deduced visits" if they are not alreay in the table (cycle breaker).

A second risk is related to the way your trigger inserts the hierarchically deduced visits:

- if the trigger used a loop to find additional nodes to insert, depending on the DB configuration,  you might invoke the trigger recursively:

  ````
  the trigger inserts visit of 2 and 1
     but while inserting 2, the trigger is invoked recursively to also insert 1
     when it then inserts 1 in the loop, it either it creates a duplicate, or a failure```
  ````
- if your trigger is impelemented the recursive way (i.e it only inserts 1 level up), you might reach some limits that might be [configuration dependent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-trigger-recursion-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).  This might cause the insertion to be incomplete in some cases.

Now all these risks can be controlled.  So it's not that it should not be done: you just need to be extra careful.

**Alternatively**, you may:

- just insert the visited location and use [recursive query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) to deduce the hierarchically bound visits when you need them.
- or add in your model something to distinguish the primary visit, and the deduced visits

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for the detailed answer. I did indeed go for just inserting the actual visited location and even though it took me ages and a lot of help I managed to get a recursive query that I could combine with some other queries to get the type of output I needed.

Comment: @jamheadart Great! Thanks for this feedback: it can really help others who face similar problems.

Comment: p.s. I like how you corrupted the country... that one worked on a couple of levels!